# TextInput value prop not taking proper state value

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I am trying to build an input field which will only take numbers as input. Minimal component definition to explain my problem is as below

```
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: 'PlaceHolder'
    }
  }

  sanitizeInput(input) {
    let sanitizedInput = input.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    this.setState({text: sanitizedInput});
  }

  render() {
    console.log("In render - ", this.state.text);
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.sanitizeInput(text)}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

But, when I am executing it, I am not getting the desired result. It seems that the TextInput is not respecting the value prop passed into it. The console.log is clearly showing desired value to be shown in `TextInput`, but I am not able to get that value properly in TextInput of device.

A video describing my problem is [posted here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uUnV7h6cZY)

Comment: And changing the `keyboardType` to `numeric` does not solve your problem?

Comment: Which version of react-native are you using? I have tested your code on RN-52, it works as expected.

Comment: @PrasunPal It's latest one. 0.54.2. I will spin up the code on RN-52 and post with my findings.

Comment: @parohy That problem can be solved by setting keyboardType to numeric, but this is just a minimalistic demonstration of the problem. I also have to format certain inputs by user, as formatting currency, sanitising text inputs, which I can not do unless this thing works as expected.

Comment: @PrasunPal - You are right. It is indeed working with 0.52.0. This is a clear regression then. But there is a  visible flicker in iOs which gets worse on Android. Can you please confirm that! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am also experiencing the behavior in RN-54 as you have specified here. I think there might be an issue with TextInput update, as both the values between 2 consecutive (number and character) input are same. like 123 -> 123x -> regEx(123x) -> 123.